# Гениальный и конгениальный

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мне никогда не попадались тексты с правильным употреблением слова "конгениальный".
Можете привести грамотные примеры его употребления? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы филологи, лингвисты и вообще ценители русского слова  облагодетельствовали нас не только "грамотными", но и "неграмотными примерами" употребления буквосочетания "конгениальный".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть предположение, что тов. Бендер не совсем правильно понимал значение своего любимого слова. Конгениальный — близкий по духу, то есть в данном случае гений — это дух. Великий комбинатор не был осведомлен о таких лингвистических тонкостях и считал по-простому: гений — он и есть гений, а конгениально — это сверхгениально.

При правильном употреблении слова в значении "близкий по духу" один предмет уподобляется другому (по смыслу, образу мыслей, манере и др.), например: "И тут обретен был человек, на мой взгляд, конгениальный самому царю ― Семен Розенцвейг"; "Русский философ конгениально интерпретировал скрытое, сакральное ядро многоликого учения немецкого мыслителя".

Возможно, что второе значение слова тоже получило бы (или получит) свое развитие. Вот, к примеру, фраза: "Вы можете конгениально и сверхискусно изображать теннис без мяча сколько угодно, но на Кубке Дэвиса вас не поймут". Но пока с любимым словом Остапа связано и сомнение в правильности, и ироничное восприятие при намеке на нашу сверхгениальность.

Comment: >"Вы можете конгениально и сверхискусно изображать теннис без мяча сколько угодно, но на Кубке Дэвиса вас не поймут". 

Боюсь, автор тут просто не в ладах с семантикой...
И подобно некоторым товарищам трактуют "конгениальный" как в "высшей степени гениальный".

Answer (score 2):

Я, когда читал "12 стульев", не знал значения этого слова и воспринимал его как "сверхгениально", что не мешало  оценивать всё высказывание как подкалывание   "отца русской демократии". Использование слова "гениально" давало тот же эффект.  Но "конгениально" смешнее, потому что не очень понятно и красиво звучит. Остап безусловно человек эрудированный, но философа-то из него зачем делать?

Comment: Вот именно.)

Answer (score 1):

София, конечно, права по сути, но есть одно но.
Бендер был человеком довольно эрудированным и любил подтрунивать над Кисой.
Думаю, он знал значение слова. И просто подкалывал соконцессионера.

Comment: Одно из двух: или не знал, или это юмор у него такой.) Ильф-то с Петровым - знали. Тут без вариантов.))

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще варианты использования слова:

"Один из собеседников Полухиной, Давид Шраер-Петров, по-моему, совершенно справедливо признает конгениальным Бродскому поэтом-современником Генриха Сапгира"

"Это идея о том, что порядок важнее, чем беспорядок, сколько бы последний ни был конгениален нашему ощущению мира." (Соломон Волков. Диалоги с Иосифом Бродским)

Answer (score 0):

Я не лингвист, но лично мне кажется, что Бендер употреблял слово "конгениально" правильно, подразумевая под этим "это близко мне по духу" = "это мне нравится"/"годится".

> — Послушайте, — сказал вдруг великий комбинатор, — как вас звали в детстве?
> — А зачем вам?
> — Да так! Не знаю; как вас называть. Воробьяниновым звать вас надоело, а Ипполитом Матвеевичем слишком кисло. Как же вас звали? Ипа?
> — Киса, — ответил Ипполит Матвеевич, усмехаясь.
> — Конгениально! Так вот что, Киса, посмотрите, пожалуйста, что у меня на спине. Болит между лопатками.

Маловероятно, что Бендер здесь использовал "конгениально" в смысле "гениально" (что гениального в имени "Киса"?), скорее всего он имел в виду именно "годится!".

P.S. Кстати, английское слово "congenial", от которого по идее происходит "конгениальный", тоже может использоваться в смысле "годный, подходящий".